# HANA : column store error: search table error: Instantiation of calculation model failed

Tags: calculated-columns, hana

In HANA I built a Calculation view which executes fine.

I have a calculated column.

Now I changed the calculated column from

```
case 
  when "Anzahl" > 1000000 then 'SUSPECT: Too high?'
  when "Anzahl" < 1000 then 'SUSPECT: Too low?'
  else 'OK'
end
```

to

```
case 
  when "Anzahl" > $$IP_UPPER_LIMIT$$ then 'SUSPECT: Too high?'
  when "Anzahl" < $$IP_LOWER_LIMIT$$ then 'SUSPECT: Too low?'
  else 'OK'
end
```

Then I get this error:

> Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [34023] Instantiation of calculation model failed;exception 306002: An internal error occurred

[image: search table error]

Answer (score 0):

Use Column Engine instead of SQL:

```
if("Anzahl"> $$IP_UPPER_LIMIT$$,'SUSPECT too high?',if("Anzahl" < $$IP_LOWER_LIMIT$$,'SUSPECT to low?','OK'))
```

[image: Calculated Column with Column Engine]

Answer (score 0):

If the input parameter has multiple entries flowing into it then we should not have single quotes for IP in the filter as shown below.

```
(in("Source",$$IP_SOURCE$$) or in('ALL',$$IP_SOURCE$$))
```

And if you have single entry flowing into the IP then you should have single quotes for IP as below:

```
(in("Source",'$$IP_SOURCE$$') or in('ALL','$$IP_SOURCE$$'))
```